# Delete method is not working in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API in my application get and post method is working fine.

This is my code:

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
       [HttpGet]
       [Route("api/Departments")]
       public List<Department> Get()
       {
            DepartmentDbContext Db = new DepartmentDbContext();
            List<Department> Departments = Db.departments.ToList();
            return Departments;
       }

       [HttpPost]
       [Route("api/Departments")]      
       public string Post([FromBody] Department department)
       {
            DepartmentDbContext Db = new DepartmentDbContext();      

            try
            {
                    Db.departments.Add(department);
                    Db.SaveChanges();
                    // return department;
                    return "Added Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Record Not Added";
            }    
       }
}
```

This code is working fine and also worked fine in postman.

But the delete method is not working - here is the code:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("api/Departments")]
public int Delete(int id)
{
    DepartmentDbContext Db = new DepartmentDbContext();

    try
    {
        Department dept = Db.departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        Db.departments.Remove(dept);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        return 1; 
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

This code is not working in postman

Comment: What you mean by "not working"? How you check that method is working or not?

Comment: are you using the HTTP verb `delete` when you're testing with Postman?

Comment: What you mean by "This code is not working in postman"?  Does the request come to the backend? Please set breakpoint and try again this. What is request's response ?

Answer (score 0):

You must send id to backend for deleting. 
Change:

```
[HttpDelete]
```

To:

```
 [HttpDelete("{id}")]
```

And then in the postman, at end of URL put id number after the last '/' and send it to backend.

Comment: @mohammed Ali Feghhi thanks for your reply ,there is a slight mistake and solved  it.the correct answer is   [HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/Departments/{id}")]

Answer (score 0):

following is the final code that works fine

```
[HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/Departments/{id}")]
        public int Delete(int id)
        {
            DepartmentDbContext Db = new DepartmentDbContext();
            try
            {
                Department dept = Db.departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                Db.departments.Remove(dept);
                Db.SaveChanges();
                return 1; //"Record Deleted Successfully";
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

                return -1; // "Record Not deleted";
            }
        }
```